# CiviPledge extension enabled but can't access

Tags: civipledge

We have recently updated CiviCRM to version 5.8.2 and we have enabled the extension  "CiviPledge".

Documentation shows that this should be visible under the "contributions" option in the dropdown list, but we cannot see it or access it at all. See pictures below showing that it is enabled and not able to be accessed in the contributions dropdown.
[image]
[image]
We had hoped that updating to version 5.8.2 would solve this problem and let us access Pledge, but unfortunately we still have no idea why we can't access it.

Additionally we have tried modifying the navigation bar to see if it's an issue with Pledge not showing up in the navigation bar, see the image below. Pledge shows up in there but any changes saved aren't actually applied. All of these are ticked as "enabled".

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't granted the CiviPledge permissions to a role your user(s) have.

Go to your Drupal permissions (https://yoursite.org/admin/people/permissions) and search for the CiviPledge permissions and grant them according to your needs.